# Prove that if $a>1$ then $\|f\| = \min\{\|f\|_\infty, a\|f\|_1\}$ is not a norm on $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $||f||=\min\{||f||_\infty, a||f||_1\}$ where $a>0$, and $||f||_\infty=\sup\limits_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|$ and $||f||_1=\int_0^1|f(x)|dx$ are two norms on $C[0,1]$. Prove that if $a>1$ then $||f||$ is not a norm on $C[0,1]$.

I tried to find some functions in $C[0,1]$ so that if $a>1$ then $||f||$ fails to satisfy triangle inequality of the norm. But I could not find such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the triangle inequality is the one to check, since it satisfies all the other axioms a norm must satisfy.

- If you pick $f$ so that $a||f||_1$ is "big" and $||f||_\infty$ is "small", then $||f||$ will be small.
- Likewise, if you pick $g$ so that $a||g||_1$ is "small" and $||g||_\infty$ is "big", then $||g||$ will still be small.
- on the other hand, $h=f+g$, then you can probably pick $f$ and $g$ so that $a||h||_1$ and $||h||_\infty$ are both "big", therefore $||h||$ will also be big.
- $f$, $g$ and $h$ together will give you your violation of the triangle inequality.

Comment: The idea might be there, but hardly a solution, not even indications thereof.

Comment: Disagree. And don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: I could not succeed totally yet. I took f(x)=x^(1/2) and g(x)=x^(5/2) but it does not work for all a>1. It works for a=2 and more values but not for all a>1.

Comment: @Bananach In case your comment (which I discover by chance) is meant to address mine, let me suggest: 1. to use the @ character next time you find yourself in a similar situation, 2. to explain why you disagree with the trivial fact stated in my first comment, 3. to explain how you reconcile your strange worldview about this with the comment now posted by the OP, 4. to stand by your words, if you want to be taken seriously, by explaining the OP how this post, without any addition, constitutes a solution, and 5. to try a little more civility in your future exchanges with me, if any.

Comment: @Infinity that's on the right track. Here's some simpler functions that work better. Let $b<1$. Let $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$. Let $g(x)=\frac1b$ on $[0,b]$, $g(x)=0$ on $(b,1]$. For any $a>1$, there is a $b$ that makes $f$, $g$ and $f+g$ violate the triangle inequality. (However, there is no $b$ that works for all $a$).

Comment: @Did calm down, maths problems are too interesting to fight over.

Comment: Actually I agree with Did this time @Bananach. The general strategy suggested here is obviously correct, but is not clear how it is applied here because for the construction of $f$ (first bullet), since $a\|f\|_1 \le a\|f\|_\infty$ holds for all $f$, it is not clear (at least to me) how $\|f\|_1$ can be big while keeping $\|f\|_\infty$ small. (That was then explained by the answerer only in the comment)

Comment: @ Michael Hartley; But $g(x)=1/b$ on $[0,b]$, $g(x)=0$ on $(b,1]$ is not in $C[0,1]$ bcz g is not continuous on [0.1].

Comment: True, true. You can approximate $g$ arbitrarily closely (under the 1-norm) with a function on $C[0,1]$ though: so let my $g$ be $g_b\not\in C[0,1]$, and then let your $g\in C[0,1]$ be such that $||g||_\infty=||g_b||_\infty$ and $||g-g_b||_1<\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$. There will be an $\epsilon$ and a $b$ that does the trick, for any given $a$.

Comment: Or, explicitly construct a suitable $g\in C[0,1]$, for example $g=\frac1b$ on $[0,b-\epsilon]$, $g=0$ on $[b+\epsilon,1]$, $g$ linear on $[b-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]$.

Comment: @MichaelHartley Who is not calm here? (Comment flagged.)